# twitter bootstrap blocks displaying

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter bootstrap for my website [mywebsite](http://www.biginfo.tn/).
I created four category blocks using `col-md-3`. When a block is heigher than the other, the other blocks don't dispay correctly. Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
            {% for category in categoriesActivities %}
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <ul class="classifieds-category">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>{{ category.name }}</a>
                            <ul class="sub-category">
                                {% for activity in category.activities %}
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ path('front_activity_details', { 'id': activity.id }) }}">{{ activity.principal }}</a>
                                    </li>     
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- End grid layout -->
            {% endfor %}
        </div> <!-- End .row -->
```

Image of the blocks:  [image]
How can i fix it?

Comment: Would you consider using a Jquery plugin (which is more expensive in resources than css of course, but came quick to my mind.) like http://masonry.desandro.com ?

Comment: Which falls back to the plugin I suggested for older browsers... If only older browsers (IE9 or below) are not an issue I would go with the css solution.

Comment: Sorry for being late. Thank you guys. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

After the Informatiqe div.
That clears the col-*-* float.